# Best way to structure database tables for users, groups, and permissions?

Tags: database-design, permissions

In my application users can join groups, and the admin of those groups can give each user different types of permissions. Users can join as many groups as they want. How would I go about structuring the database tables?

```
   Users       Groups          Permissions        Group_User_Permissions
-----------  -----------   -------------------   -----------------------
| UID(pk) |  | GID(pk) |   | PID(pk) | VALUE |     | UID | GID | PID |
```

Is that the proper way of doing this?
Or is this necessary:

```
   Users        Groups         Permissions            User_Groups          Group_User_Permissions
-----------  -----------   -------------------  ------------------------  -----------------------
| UID(pk) |  | GID(pk) |   | PID(pk) | VALUE |  | UGID(pk) | UID | GID |     | UGID(pk) | PID |
```

Obviously performance is important, but I am not really sure what one will fair better in the end. any ideas?

Comment: Just a couple of observations; Group_User_Permissions would appear to have a 1-1 correalation with user_groups, so I can't see why it's a separate table. From that, I cannot see that UGID offers any useful purpose.

Comment: ya, i was thinking i would use `UGID` because it would be an `AI`  `PK`, making it join faster, and also limiting the amount of rows in `User_Groups`. But that was just an idea. i am not really sure which is better.

Comment: Why would it 'join faster'? The first model seems fine to me (but I'm no expert).

Comment: im not sure, just an idea

Comment: You have two msny to many relationships (users - groups and groups - permissons) . Whst exactly is the problem modelling these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider that are 3 `permissions` for a `group A` with GID =100 :

- Read (PID=1)
- Write (PID=2)
- Execute (PID=3)
  And there is a user that belongs to `group A` with `UID=1001`.
  Let's take the example of the `UserID=1001` in the `group A` :

  UID  GID PID
  1001 100 1
  1001 100 2
  1001 100 3

This is a many-to-many relationship between a `User`, a `Permission` and a `Group`.
The compound key  `(UID,GID,PID)` is a Primary Key and each key is a Foreign Key.

Having  `Group_User_Permissions` will add an extra relationship and I don't see it useful. (extra join = complex query)